# Can I read a text file into objects from my classes and read in VO in JAVA ADF?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have a text file which is being parsed to some objects from classes predefined by me. I want to use those objects to add them to JSF pages in JAVA ADF. can it be done in this way using the View objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right click your java classes to expose them as data controls you can drag into an ADF UI page.
Basic tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_bean_dc/tut_bean_dc.html